# HeidiSQL is not showing any data even when table size is more than 0B

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heidisql

I have Postgresql Database in production and i'm trying to insert data from my localhost using `psycopg2` library. i'm seeing my database through HeidiSQL. But after i finished inserting the data, my HeidiSQL shows that table size increased but when i try to see the data, it shows 0 rows. I have tried to drop all tables and re-migrate and re-insert the data, but still it shows 0 rows even when the table size is not 0 B.

I have tried to insert table one by one from the program by comment the other insert and it works. But i still can't understand why i can't see any data when i'm inserting simultaneously

[image: Database After Migrate]

[image: Database After Inserting]

Comment: Are you refreshing the display after doing the insert?  The display does not automatically refresh.  I see you have a filter set, are you sure the filter still applies?

Comment: i have restarted heidisql after i insert my data. And my filter is not set. `id>0` filter is recent filter

Comment: Perhaps you don't run HeidiSQL in autocommit mode and forgot to `COMMIT`.